# Counter-symmetric binary relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

In the lecture pdf our teacher sent us, some of binary relation properties are described. I understood all of properties except **counter-symmetric**. Here is the definition of it from the pdf:
$$\forall x, y \in X: xRy \Rightarrow \neg(yRx)$$
I understand the antisymmetric relations - if there is $(a,b)$ then $(b,a)$ can't be in the relation set, unless $a=b$. That given, I have no idea what the logic behind counter-symmetry can be.

Could someone please explain it with some examples?

Comment: Well going by your definition of "counter-symmetric" : An antisymmetric relation may be reflexive , irreflexive or neither; however a counter-symmetric relation must be irreflexive. I must say though, I've never seen the term "counter-symmetric" before.

Comment: @Kaind I thought about the same thing, but later in the same pdf when it describes closure of relations, it says: "Notice: the closure of relation may not exist (example?: a counter-symmetric closure of a symmetric relation, etc.)". I thought about it, and I think an antisymmetric relation closure can't exist for a symmetric one, however a counter-symmetric may exist if it may be reflexive as you described.

Comment: 1. A symmetric relation has NO anti-symmetric closure is FALSE. Eg: The empty relation. 2. A reflexive relation has NO counter-symmetric closure is TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this property is usually called *asymmetry* of $R$.

Given a relation $R$ on a set $X$ and distinct elements $x,y\in X$, four things are possible:

- $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}x$;
- $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\not\mathrel{R}x$;
- $x\not\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}x$; or
- $x\not\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\not\mathrel{R}x$.

$R$ is antisymmetric the first is true only when $x=y$. $R$ is asymmetric (or counter-symmetric) if the first is **never** true. (Note that in particular this implies that $R$ is irreflexive: there is no $x\in X$ such that $x\mathrel{R}x$.)